# tensorflow for classifying unknown input

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, data-analysis

I have been working on convolutional neural networks for image classification.  I've gotten an assignment where they gave me a text file containing input/output pairs, where the output is either 0 or 1, while input is generated values.
For example

```
0   X225006700,X773579,X236398246,X773545,X51769735,X315340932,X44092910,Y2,Y1132,Y2257,Y2793,Y1080,Y1555,Y1222,Y2072,Y1238,Y1791,Y1705,Y2684,Y1725,Y2641,Y2640,Y1690,Y1367,Y1353,Y2949,Y2557,Y1478,Y2024,Y1486,Y1522,Y1456,Y1940,Y977,Y1468,Z4,Z15

0   X123474229,X51578397,X40087170,X236398246,X367227997,X62716661,X127972441,X344420902,X40087738,X103413307,X51769735,X524837224,X37875376,X79805718,X773579,X44092910,Y1353,Y1555,Y2849,Y1478,Y2321,Y1238,Y1486,Y3143,Y1522,Y2817,Y1702,Y1940,Z4,Z15,Z29

1   X62716661,X277692318,Y1367,Y3269,Y1353,Y2949,Y2814,Y2267,Y2257,Y3250,Y3021,Y2557,Y3232,Y1080,Y1555,Y1222,Y2849,Y1478,Y2321,Y3145,Y1486,Y3143,Y1791,Y1522,Y2817,Y1702,Y1456,Y2641,Y2640,Y1940,Y1468,Y2170,Y3585,Z4,Z15,Z27
```

Now with normal neural networks, I always need (at least that I know of) specified input numbers in order to create input layer (e.g. 10x10 pixel images, or cat/dog/bird etc). Is it possible to do the same for these random inputs?
If not, is there any recommended method for solving this problem? (I'm thinking using matlab since there appears to be xyz values in the data)

Comment: Hey Andy Wei, Is that the input data vector's size is varying with every sample?

Comment: it appears so, some inputs only has length of 5, some 9, etc

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to know how to build a neural-network-based classifier that maps text strings of arbitrary length to a 0 or a 1. There are multiple ways to achieve this. One way is to map each text string to a constant-sized vector using some featurization scheme (e.g., bag of words), and then feed these constant-sized vectors as input to your model. Another way is to use a sequence model like an RNN, padding your examples to a constant length (e.g., the length of the longest string).